# Reading a Date/Time record from MS Access Database using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I spent a lot of time looking for an answer to this problem I have. I have found many solutions on the internet, but none that were able to help me enough to solve this particular problem.

I have an MS Access Database. I added it to my VB.net project and I'm able to add/delete, and display records in the gridView.

I want to create a piece of code that is similar to the following pseudo-code:

```
Dim x as integer = 8

Loop for as many rows (entries) as the database contains
    If ((x > column3_of_database_value) and (x < column4_of_database_value)  
       Do something
       Break out of loop
    Else
       Move to next database row (entry)
Next
```

Please let me know how to reformat this pseudo-code to a working VB.net code. Thank you kindly,

Robert Gohn

Comment: The title may seem misleading. Eventually the variable x wont be an integer. It will be a date/time value, however, once I have the basic concept working, I will modify the code to work for a Date/Time variable

Comment: I believe you have some binding with the gridview and the database, which allowed you to add/delete records. Then why don't you try looping through the rows of the gridview and do the stuff you wanted?